# Mysql web server 404 not found error

Tags: android, server, webserver, wamp

My app was working well before all of a sudden stopped working. Now when I try to register or login a user the server returns a "not found" message.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalled wamp server and granting permissions, all to no avail.

How can I fix this?

Comment: post some code or Log which you tried.. generally 404 means  the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Comment: I think the problem is  with server configuration

Comment: @ShylendraMadda do you mean the problem could be from my code?

Comment: May be it is because of your requested URL not found in server

Comment: friend can you  show us error please?

Comment: What color is the WAMPServer icon in the system tray?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's green

Comment: Consider specifying, code/configuration or anything else that you have changed between then and now.

Comment: @Himanshu the only thing I've changed is my layouts and also added some activities  didn't touch the server side. the funniest thing is that the URL works perfectly in my normal browser

Comment: Check if you can access ANY URL from your app, in case your app no longer has permissions to access the web.